# 5x vshost.exe in Windows Firewall Exceptions

Tags: windows, virus, firewall

Under **Windows Firewall Exceptions** I see 5 instances of **vshost.exe**. Is this normal, or should I be worried?  I do run weekly scans with AVG Free, and have Windows Firewall on, that's basically all my protection.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Visual Studio to develop network connected applications?  **vshost.exe** is the debugger hosting process.  Anytime you debug an application in Visual Studio the hosting process is the actual process that is running and as such, has firewall exceptions for any app that acts as a network server.  I'm pretty sure that **vshost.exe** always need at least couple exception, so I wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: aha.. yes I do develop some programs with socket connections, TcpClient.. Good, then should be no worry. Cheers!